# Today Extension widget is not loading on iphone 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, ios8-today-widget

I have an application that contains a widget (Today Extension). My application has been approved by Apple, but it still has an issue with iPhone6+ that I have managed to locate.

When launching my app on this device from within xCode it works fine, and the widget is shown, but when trying to open the app that gets installed from **testfly** or from an exported **adHoc .ipa** it is unable to open the widget.

I have being searching across the net but I have the settings recommended:

..in valid architectures:

**arm64 armv7 armv7s armv64**

..and in Architectures

it has its defaults as **Standard architectures** that includes  **arm64** and **armv7s**

Any ideas of what can be making this happen?

Comment: Did you find any clues on it?

Comment: Hi @jeeeyul I solved this issue taking into account and checking for memory issues and usage. But, after reducing the app into its minimum (the device for the one I was testing were always sending me Memory warnings), I realise that the problem was an error that only appears when debugging the app. The main problem is that debugger for Today Extensions sucks for this error and does not stop at line. "Memory Error" Is all It says..

Comment: So, Your inference is that the iPhone6+ may needs more memory to display widget properly? I have same problem, only iPhone6+ users can't see widget properly. My widget  uses pretty less memory 6 to 30MB.

Comment: Some sort of, I do not claim that it's the main reason, I'm not discarding some newbie error on my code, but It happens to be this way, As iPhone 6+ loads 3x images it needs more memory to run widgets, and, if the memory limit is the same for all widgets, disregarding device, ...then this is a real problem...I had same issue with an iPad later. But still, my problem is somewhat more weird than that...Maybe I should update my question or ask another one with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: any solutions found on this? Im actually seeing this issue now.. Im not fetching any data, just loading a tableview with 2 dummy cells as a today widget..

Comment: Hi @JAManfredi, you may want to take a look to how big the Font you are using is, it's also weird, but in my case, any time I was setting a Font to size 16 into a label, that was leading into a crash.

Comment: @HugoAlonso thanks for the reply, I actually figured it out. I was using a custom font, as soon as I switched it to "System" the memory issues stopped.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I'm going ahead and answer this question. Please bear in mind that
>   these are tips, not exactly a solution for all scenarios.

Main reasons for the app to crash are linked to *out of memory* issues:

- Remember that in **iPhone 6+** the images that are shown are the ones in **3X**. So keep them at minimum number and size.
- Avoid custom Fonts.
- Avoid Font sizes bigger than 14 points. (This limit can be lower if you use other memory consuming items)
- `UIViewControllers` embedded at `UIContainersView` are loaded at launch. This causes a surge in memory usage.
- Prefer using a `NavigationController` as your **`InitialView`** (If you are going to present more that one view)
- If there is a secondary or terciary `UIViewController`, that could possibly not be shown to the user, unless the user really needs to see it or want to (for example, a configuration view), or just do not need to be loaded prior, put that `UIViewController` in another **`Storyboard`** and load it programmatically when needed.